# Incorporating MALTAB FIS into continuous loop

Tags: matlab, fuzzy-logic

I am currently using two Arduino microcontrollers to read in two sets of data and send the data to MATLAB via Bluetooth. In the code, MATLAB reads in the serial data, sends it through a series of nested 'if' loops to organize the data. Once organized, the stored data is used as inputs for a Fuzzy. The issue I am having is with the Fuzzy. When I try to use the stored data as inputs (numeric), I receive an error that they are empty, even though MATLAB displays the data without an issue.

Here is my code (ignore 'x' 'y' 'z' variables, these are not being used in the FIS) :

```
a = Bluetooth('HC-05',1);

b = Bluetooth('IN',1)

a.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';

b.ReadAsyncMode = 'continuous';

fopen(a); %data collector A

fopen(b); %data collector B

%A data points

heartRateVarA=0;

temperatureVarA=0;

xVarA=0;

yVarA=0;

zVarA=0;

%B data points

heartRateVarB=0;

temperatureVarB=0;

xVarB=0;

yVarB=0;

zVarB=0;

%A & B loop --- Uses 'fgets' to collect 2 lines of data, one per declared

%variable before parsing into corresponding variable

while (a.Status == 'open')&(b.Status=='open')

for i=1 : 1 : 2

 matchA = fgets(a);    `

 matchB = fgets(b);


 testA=contains(matchA,'Celsius');

 testB = contains(matchB,'Celsius'); 

 if (testA==1)
     temperatureVarA=matchA;
 else
     testA=contains(matchA,'BPM');
     if(testA==1)
         heartRateVarA=matchA;
     else
         testA=contains(matchA,'X:');
         if(testA==1)
             xVarA=matchA;
         else
             testA=contains(matchA,'Y:');
             if(testA==1)
                yVarA=matchA;
             else
                 testA=contains(matchA,'Z:');
                 if(testA==1)
                     zVarA=matchA;
                 end
             end
         end    
     end
 end

 if (testB==1)
     temperatureVarB=matchB;
 else
     testB=contains(matchB,'BPM');
     if(testB==1)
         heartRateVarB=matchB;
     else
         testB=contains(matchB,'X:');
         if(testB==1)
             xVarB=matchB;
         else
             testB=contains(matchB,'Y:');
             if(testB==1)
                yVarB=matchB;
             else
                 testB=contains(matchB,'Z:');
                 if(testB==1)
                     zVarB=matchB;
                 end
             end
         end    
     end
 end

end

    %Display read and parsed in data

    fprintf('Heart Rate A : '); disp(heartRateVarA);

    fprintf('Temperature A : '); disp(temperatureVarA);

    %fprintf('X A : '); disp(xVarA);

    %fprintf('Y A : '); disp(yVarA);

    %fprintf('Z A : '); disp(zVarA);

    fprintf('Heart Rate B : '); disp(heartRateVarB);
    fprintf('Temperature B : '); disp(temperatureVarB);
    %fprintf('X B : '); disp(xVarB);
    %fprintf('Y B : '); disp(yVarB);
    %fprintf('Z B : '); disp(zVarB);

   %FIS eval --- treats stored values of HR and temp variables as inputs
    fis=FuzzyPrototype;
    outputA = evalfis([heartRateVarA temperatureVarA],fis);
    outputB = evalfis([heartRateVarB temperatureVarB],fis);`

    disp(outputA)
    disp(outputB)

    if(a.Status ~= 'open')|(b.Status ~= 'open')
       break;
    end

pause(20);   

end
```

The error I receive is this : "The first argument should have as many columns as input variables and
as many rows as independent sets of input values."

Answer (score 0):

Error was caused by the inputs NOT being double. By incorporating 'str2double', I could convert the inputs to double and enter into the FIS.